# How can I remove a square button in the Network center on the task bar on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, internet

I want to remove square buttons I don't use so there is no chance for me to occasionally click on them. I can easily do it with the notification center but don't see how it is possible with the Network center.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove square buttons I don't use so there is no chance for me to occasionally click on them.

While it might not be possible to remove the button, you can make it so, Mobile Hotspot cannot accidentally be enabled.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network Connections

Configure, **NC_ShowSharedAccessUI**, to be the value of **0**.  I suspect that by disabling the ability to share your internet, the button will actually disappear.

Source: [How to Enable or Disable Mobile Hotspot in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/106796-enable-disable-mobile-hotspot-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score -1):

I did some more looking for this issue and you cannot do what you wish to do. That button is part of the settings program and cannot be customized